# How can I run this app on Heroku or similar?

Tags: node.js, heroku, dotcloud, paas

I would like to get this app:
  https://github.com/lysol/typeto.me/

running on Heroku (or some similar service).

What steps would I need to follow? I'm having a great deal of trouble understanding what to put where.

I already know I need to do something like this:
  [Can I run coffeescript in Heroku?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6356267/can-i-run-coffeescript-in-heroku?rq=1)
for the coffeescript stuff.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So this is super easy to run on [dotCloud.com](http://dotcloud.com)

Here is a [demo](http://typetome-dotcloud-labs.dotcloud.com/) I just pushed.

Just clone this [fork](https://github.com/3on/typeto.me) and push it to dotcloud.

1. create an account on [dotcloud.com](https://www.dotcloud.com/)
2. [install](http://docs.dotcloud.com/firststeps/install/) the cli tool
3. clone the repo `git clone git://github.com/3on/typeto.me.git` and `cd typeto.me`
4. edit the config file and put right value for "publicHost" `typetome-[your dotcloud login].dotcloud.com`
5. create an app `dotcloud create typetome`
6. push it to the cloud `dotcloud push typetome`

And that's it!

Comment: This is great! Can you send me an email? dmd@3e.org - I see you work for dotCloud and have some questions for you.

Comment: I can and should remove our email address.

Answer (score 0):

Heroku has a [great article on deploying node.js apps](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs) at their devcenter. It is fairly simple, assuming you use NPM for packages, and git for version control.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this site http://wedeploy.com/ with suport Node, Ruby, MongoDB, and others services. Have simple client to manage your apps.